# Search by Single and multiple Key Words both from single textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var db = new MatriModel();
string s = txtKeyWord.Text;
string[] words = s.Split(',');
int count = words.Length;

if (count <= 5)
{
    SerachByKeyWordPanel.Visible = true;
    var KeyWord = db.tblProfiles.Where(x => words.Contains(x.tblCaste.Caste) && words.Contains(x.tblCountry.Country) && words.Contains(x.City) && words.Contains(x.tblOccupation.Occupation) && words.Contains(x.tblMotherTongue.MotherTongue)).Select(x => new
  {
        ProfileID = x.ProfileID,
        ProfileFor = x.tblProfileFor.ProfileFor,
  }.ToList();
```

By Above code I can get details for multiple keywords but at the same time, I want to get records by single keyword also.

Please some one help me, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not related to your problem but... why on earth you write this? _if (count <= Convert.ToInt16("5"))_

Comment: If the code already works with multiple search-words i expect that it also works for a single(if `s.Split(',')` returns only one). If not you have to explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Not is says no record found, by single keyword

Comment: your result need to have the words in all columns. To check some (what I suspect you want) is to change the `&&` (and) to `||` (or)

Comment: with using && need to get by single and multiple keyword.

Comment: @Steve you made my day, lol :D

Comment: `&&` means any of the words must be in all columns. If you use a single word, that single word must be in all columns for a result to be returned. If you have words `"home,away"` then all the queried columns must have the word "home" or "away" in it. If you just use `"home"`, all the queried columns must equal "home". You, however, have columns like `MotherTongue`, `City` and `Occupation`. One word will probably never match all those columns

Answer (score 0):

See the following code snippet based on a simplified object:

```
class MatrixModel {
    public string ProfileId {get; set;}
    public string Caste {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string Occupation {get; set;}
    public string MotherTongue {get; set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    var db = new MatrixModel[]{
        new MatrixModel {
            ProfileId = "1",
            Caste = "Caste1",
            Country = "USA",
            City = "Miami",
            Occupation = "System administrator",
            MotherTongue = "English"
        },
        new MatrixModel {
            ProfileId = "2",
            Caste = "Caste1",
            Country = "India",
            City = "Mumbai",
            Occupation = "developer",
            MotherTongue = "English"
        },      
        new MatrixModel {
            ProfileId = "3",
            Caste = "Caste1",
            Country = "England",
            City = "London",
            Occupation = "developer",
            MotherTongue = "English"
        },              
    };
    string s = "Caste1, England";
    string[] words = s.Split(',');
    int count = words.Length;

    if (count <= 5)
    {
                IEnumerable<MatrixModel> KeyWord = db;
                foreach(var par in words) 
                {
                    var parTrimmed = par.Trim();
                    KeyWord = KeyWord
                        .Where(x => x.Caste == parTrimmed
                            || x.Country == parTrimmed
                            || x.City == parTrimmed
                            || x.Occupation == parTrimmed 
                            || x.MotherTongue == parTrimmed);
                }

                var result = KeyWord.Select(x => new
                    {
                        ProfileID = x.ProfileId,
                    }).ToList();

                foreach(var item in result){
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
        }
}
```

The result is the following:

```
{ ProfileID = 3 }
```

Comment: I suggested `||` but was told no by the OP. The `count <= 5` suggests the keywords are supposed to be for each column respectively - since there are also 5 columns being checked - but there could possibly be less, which is where there is a problem imo. If the search keywords were seperated `,,,developer,` we could fashion some hack...

Comment: I think the problem the OP has with `||` is that if he wants all 'developers' from 'Mumbai' and uses keywords `"developer,Mumbai"` the result will contain incorrect records

Comment: Why we need to create a class, already we are having all the data in tabels ex:(x.tblCaste.Caste) etc

Comment: @akileshkhoday That was just a working sample. We don't have your data in your tables

Comment: if we enter two keywords then get records with both matching criteria record, not each record

Comment: if i type cast1, England get only those records which has both cast1 and England

Comment: @akileshkhoday I got what you mean, please see my updated answer

Comment: IEnumerable<MatriModel> KeyWord = db; show error for 'db' as cannot implicate convert type models.MatriModel to system,collection,geniric.Ienumareble<MatriModel >, an explict coverstion exist

Comment: @akileshkhoday in your case you should do something like this: IEnumerable<MatriModel> KeyWord = db.tblProfiles;

Comment: still it says models.MatriModel to system,collection,geniric.Ienumareble<MatriModel >, an explict coverstion exist

Comment: Show me the line of code, you are doing something wrong, my example works perfectly

Comment: IEnumerable<MatriModel> KeyWords = (IEnumerable<MatriModel>)db.tblProfiles;
                    foreach (var par in words)
                    {
                        var parTrimmed = par.Trim();
                        KeyWords = KeyWords.Where(x => x.tblCastes.caste)
                    }

Comment: after typing x.tblcastes i should get x.tblcastes.caste, but intellisense is not showing .cast. it says db<tblcast> doesnot contain any defination for cast and no extension method cast acccepting a frist argumrnt of type Dbset<tblcast> could be found (are you missing a user directive or an assembley reference?)

Comment: @akileshkhoday I don't exactly know as I'm not seeing your code. My answer is working, you can test it. I don't know how to adapt it to your usee case. You should just get back an enumerable and it will work

Comment: @akileshkhoday it's an easy task, you should just get back an IEnumberable from EF, nothing complex here.

Comment: But while I am assigning my db.tblprofiles to IEnumberable<MatriModel> it says "still it says models.MatriModel to system,collection,geniric.Ienumareble<MatriModel >, an explict coverstion exist"

Comment: I don't know how to help you sorry